# How to edit xml node value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm writing a custom plugin for use in my website using Jw player adtonomy plugin which loads adverts from XML files. However I do not know how to update the nodes in the files. I have tried using simple xml but I don't know how to update. Any implementation is highly regarded. Thanks. Here is the xml file.

```
<xml>
<plugins>adtimage</plugins>
<adtimage.graphic>http://mysite/default.png</adtimage.graphic>
<adtimage.link>http://targetsite.com</adtimage.link>
<adtimage.positions>pre,post</adtimage.positions>
<adtimage.onpause>true</adtimage.onpause>
<adtimage.txt>Advertisement</adtimage.txt>
<adtimage.btntxt>Click to continue with video</adtimage.btntxt>
</xml>
```

my code is here.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
 echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";

 /*
   TO DO
   change the node value of 
   <adtimage.graphic>http://mysite/default.png</adtimage.graphic>
   to
   <adtimage.graphic>http://stackoverflow.com</adtimage.graphic>
 */
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
//Load XML
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

// Modify a node
$xml->{"adtimage.graphic"} = 'http://stackoverflow.com/adtimage.graphic';

// Saving the whole modified XML to a new filename
$xml->asXml('updated.xml');
```

Example Output **'updated.xml'**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<plugins>adtimage</plugins>
<adtimage.graphic>http://stackoverflow.com/adtimage.graphic</adtimage.graphic>
<adtimage.link>http://targetsite.com</adtimage.link>
<adtimage.positions>pre,post</adtimage.positions>
<adtimage.onpause>true</adtimage.onpause>
<adtimage.txt>Advertisement</adtimage.txt>
<adtimage.btntxt>Click to continue with video</adtimage.btntxt>
</xml>
```